# Excel - 3 pages in Print Preview - 4 in Printout

Tags: excel, vba

Printpreview of an Excel worksheet is generated using VBA. The Print Preview shows 3 sheets numbered 1/3,2/3 and 3/3. When sent to the printer, 4 pages are printed numbered 1/4, 2/4, 3/4 and 4/4.

How do I fix the problem?

Comment: Are you printing on the default printer?

Comment: Where's your VBA code?

Comment: Thanks for offering help. I have identified the issue. Am posting it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "rows to repeat at the top" in "Print Titles" had 10 rows of which two were hidden. When I deleted those hidden rows and then ran the code, the print preview and print out are now in sync. I concluded that the rows were creating the confusion.